# Programmatically created ToolBar items not working on some of the frame positions

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uitoolbar

I am having weird problem with Programmatically created UIToolbar and UIWebView

UIWebView frame size can be changed and tool bar position is calculated at runtime.

Problem is, UIToolBar is not taking any touch events or UIBarButtenItems are not clickable
for certain frame sizes.

Kind of pattern like, if webView starts from xy(0,0) everything is fine.
as you move webview to center, uitoolbar buttons below half works and so on..

**Tested**

Web View is not overlapping at any point.
Already tried with bound for UIToolBar

**Structure I am using.**

(Custom/Pro grammatically/No Nibs) created UIView with UIWebView and UIToolBar, 
then inside UIViewController creating UIView with desired frame.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you using view's inside views. how you setting the frame ? you should use bound not the frame..

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, and then did the following and it worked:

```
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
toolbar.bounds = self.view.bounds;
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 30);
```

So the key is to set bounds to the parent view's bounds.